# Windows tool to diff 3 or more files

Tags: windows, plain-text, diff, comparison

I am looking for a tool for Windows. It must allow comparing at least 3 text blocks. Any recommendations?

**Update:** 4 or more files at the same time is even better

Comment: Quite a few will handle 3 files. I know of none that will handle more. Is more than 3 a hard requirement, or are 3 sufficient?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I think 3+ or ideally unlimited is best.

Comment: Your choice, but please state a value. 4 is 3+, so is 5.. Do you want unlimited, or is there some realistic number? Frankly, there are a few which handle 3 - and none which handle 4. Go ahead and demand more, if you want to; but expect to be disspaointed.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I know. That's why I said "at least 3" so I have at least something.

Comment: I was just afraid that your "`4 or more files at the same time is even better`" would pout people off mentioning those that can only handle 3. But, nvm, you have some good responses

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements, as stated, are minimal.

[WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/) will accomplish what you want.  Specifically, it allows comparing three text files.

It is open-source, with the source code located [here](https://github.com/winmerge/winmerge).

It is freeware and donations are accepted [here](https://sourceforge.net/donate/index.php?group_id=13216).

Answer (score 0):

[**Meld**](https://meldmerge.org/) allows three-way comparison of files.

It is free and open source. There is an installer for Windows. Not that you need it, but others stumbling on this question might be interested in other platforms: It can be installed using the package manager on common Linux distributions; and though Mac isn't officially supported, there are some installers available for it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[kDIFF3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) will, as its name suggests, allow you to diff 3 files.

It is free, open source, well supported and :

- compares or merges two or three text input files or directories,
- shows the differences line by line and character by character (!),
- provides an automatic merge-facility and an integrated editor for -   comfortable solving of merge-conflicts,
- supports Unicode, UTF-8 and
  other codecs, autodetection via byte-order-mark "BOM" supports KIO on  KDE (allows accessing ftp, sftp, fish, smb etc.),
- Printing of
  differences,
- Manual alignment of lines,
- Automatic merging of version   control history ($Log$),
- and has an intuitive graphical user   interface.
- Windows-Explorer integration Diff-Ext-for-KDiff3 - shell
  extension included in installer

[image]